# unable to extend the hover button to cover the selected item when ever someone select an item

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I will really appreciate if any one can help out. i have been trying to extend my hover to cover the full width  of a specific item when selected but to no avail, i have been on it  for hours and i have search the whole internet but nothings works out for me, i would so much appreciate a help,
below is the css

````
```React
import React, {useState} from 'react'

import styled from "styled-components"

const NavRow = ({selected,Icon,title}) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false)



  return (
    <>  
    {active && selected} 
    <Container onClick={()=> setActive(!active)} active= {active}>
       <IconBtn onClick={()=> setActive(!active)} active={active}>   
      <Icon/>
      </IconBtn>

    <Title onClick={()=> setActive(!active)} active={active} >
  <h4> {title}</h4>
  </Title>
    
    </Container>

    </>
  )
}

export default NavRow

const Container = styled.div`

display:flex;
align-items:center;

margin-top:-10px ;
box-sizing:border-box;



&:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:lightgray;

}

@media (max-width:768px) {
      width:30vw;
      height:5vh;
     margin:3px ;
      &:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:lightgray;
    box-sizing:border-box;

    
   
    
      }



  }
   
background-color: ${(props)=> props.active ? "lightgray" : " " }
   
`

const Title  = styled.div`
font-weight:600;
font-size:11px;
flex:1;

&:hover{
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
   
}
font-weight: ${(props)=> props.active ? "800" : ""};
white-space : nowrap;
margin-left:8px;

    

`

const IconBtn = styled.div`
color:#606060;
font-size:large !important;
margin-bottom:10px;


&:hover{
color:red;
}
color: ${(props)=> props.active ? "red" : " "};
````

Answer (score 0):

please use `display: inline-block;` **css** so that its will take full container.

Comment: ok thank you but should i add the display: inline-block on the hover effect itself or in the container

Comment: it didn't work out please any more suggestion i will appreciate